# how can i store results query results to a "public" variable in Nodejs ?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I store results Data into a variable that can I use outside?

My query is like this

```
let array = [];

const a = 0,
      b = 1;

 if  ( a < b)  {
   const result = await DataClass.findOne({feld:"Word"}).exec();
   array.push(result);
}

// continue ....

console.log(array)
```

or like this :

```
let array = [];

const a = 0,
      b = 1;

 if  ( a < b)  {
   await DataClass.findOne({feld:"Word"}).then( result =>{
    array.push(result);
   });
}

// Code continue ....

console.log(array)
```

How can I store results Data into a variable that can I use outside?

Comment: Please see [How do I return the response from an aynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992), which this duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tryed environment variables?
in .env

```
ARRAY=''
```

and in your file

```
process.env.ARRAY = array
```